# Two local branches tracks two remotes, how can auto-push only one?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have run

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: XXX/client.git
  Push  URL: XXX/client.git
  HEAD branch: (unknown)
  Remote branches:
    cancun                    tracked
    cancun_elad               tracked
    dragon                    tracked
    piano                     tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    cancun_elad merges with remote cancun_elad
    piano       merges with remote piano
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    cancun_elad pushes to cancun_elad (up to date)
    piano       pushes to piano       (local out of date)
```

and then I have run

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 710, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (146/146), done.
Writing objects: 100% (426/426), 5.57 MiB | 1.05 MiB/s, done.
Total 426 (delta 353), reused 324 (delta 266)
To XXXX/client.git
   65c11e9..72b8931  cancun_elad -> cancun_elad
 ! [rejected]        piano -> piano (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to ' XXX/client.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration
hint: variable to 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

Does this mean I have pushed **both** local `piano` and `cancun_elad`? If so, how can I revert `piano` push?

How can I configure `git push` to push only one of the local branches (`cancun_elad`)?
where is the `push.default` ?

Comment: What version of Git are you using (`git --version`)?  What is `push.default` currently set to (`git config push.default`)?  You may need to add the `--global` flag to the last command.

Comment: git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)

Comment: `$ git config --global push.default` returned nothing

Comment: What about `git config push.default` in your repo?  IIRC, 1.7.12.4 was set up to use `simple` as `push.default` out-of-the-box.  So it seems like you have a setting somewhere to use `matching`, which would push all tracking branches for a remote.  FWIW, `matching` used to be the default, which is why I asked for the version number.  Also, if it returns nothing with either command, then that just means it's using the default setting (which really should be `simple` in this case).

Comment: $ git status
error: Malformed value for push.default: --global
error: Must be one of nothing, matching, simple, upstream or current.
fatal: bad config file line 19 in .git/config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, unless you re-ran the last `git push` with the `--force` (`-f`) option, you should be okay.  While it attempted to update `piano`, it didn't actually do it because it was a non-fast-forward update.

Generally, the best place to set `push.default` is in your `~/.gitconfig`.  In this case, I think you're looking for `push.default` to be set to `upstream`.  The [`git-config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man page has more information about other values, if you're interested.  Just search on `push.default`.

You can just edit `~/.gitconfig` and include:

```
[push]
    default = upstream
```

Or, run:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

Either one will do the trick.

Note: `upstream` is the literal word `upstream`, not the name of the branch you want to track.

```
:: git config --global push.default upstream
:: git config -l | grep push.default
push.default=upstream
```

Comment: `While it attempted to update piano, it didn't actually do it ` but did it push `cancun_elad` for sure?

Comment: fatal: bad config file line 15 in /Users/eladb/.gitconfig       here:  [push]
 default = origin\cancun_elad

Comment: Yes, `cancun_elad` was updated.  `cat ~/.gitconfig` doesn't show anything?  It should.  Did you ever set `user.name` and `user.email`?

Comment: No, no.  Don't set it to the branch name, set it literally to the word `upstream`, just like in my example.

Comment: see: $ git status
error: Malformed value for push.default: --global
error: Must be one of nothing, matching, simple, upstream or current.
fatal: bad config file line 19 in .git/config

Comment: Please, run the command exactly as I have above: `git config --global push.default upstream`.

Comment: If it's not working (as in it's still pushing all tracking branches--not complaining about a config error), then it may mean you have `push.default` set in your local repository.  You can try running `git config --local push.default upstream` in the local repo, or `git config --local unset push.default` to rectify it.

Comment: I did...but even if i remove the last section i get error when running status

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35749/discussion-between-jszakmeister-and-elad-benda)

Comment: BTW, that should be `git config --local --unset push.default`.  My apologies for saying the wrong thing.